# xamarin auto layout is not working - it doesn't respect the constraints while it's fully constrainted

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm using the auto layout in storyboards in a Xamarin.iOS project.
why is my constrains not respected when I switch from Iphone4 to iPhone 5 or o Iphon6 etc.

I tried in all modes... I also tried to design in GENERIC mode and it the label, button are staying in fixed position on the Screen and it cut's off it shows orange when I switch to different render modes in Xamarin Studio - designer.

AutoLayout, size classing is checked on! and the controls are fully constrained in other words has x,y,height, width etc. are set.

I also followed this short introduction video about AutoLAyout, but I don't get the same results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDlCx0C3v74

**2nd ISSUE I have is:**
   When I make changes in the properties e.g. the height from 21 to 30 and I press the "update frames based on constraints" then I expect the height on the designer is going to be adjust to 30. But when I click on the "Update frames..." button then the property value is set back to 21... I thought this should be other way around... !!!!

any advice?

Xamarin Studio
Version 6.1.3 (build 19) 
[image: designed in GENERIC]

switch to Iphone6
[image: iphone 6 view]

switch to iPhone 4
[image]

UPDATED (storyboard code added)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11762" systemVersion="16C67" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r" launchScreen="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11757"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Hi there this is a label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="3" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO">
                                <rect key="frame" x="225" y="290" width="254" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint id="10" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="height" constant="21"/>
                                    <constraint id="13" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="width" constant="254"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="one more label is here" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="4" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES">
                                <rect key="frame" x="225" y="344" width="231" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint id="9" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" constant="225"/>
                            <constraint id="12" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="270"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample project? Autolayout issues are not easy to debug without directly looking at the storyboard

Comment: @BytesGuy: I posted the code and the print screen... So I want that the layout should fit in Iphone4/5/6 etc and maybe also in IPAD as well if there is no big effort to do... Therefore I choose to the design in Generic mode, but as you can see it doesn't respect the Constrains.!!!!

Comment: @ethem Hi there. HAve you been fixed it? I remember,that i tried Xamarin.iOS and autolayout worked pretty nice(year ago). But now,with lastest SDK/IDE i have the same problem,constraints are work incorrect(this button "+" on Xamarin.iOS designer,that adds four constraints)
ANy ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience the iOS Designer can be quite buggy, and especially for constraints its easier to use interface builder.

`right click on the storyboard` > `Open with` > `Xcode Interface builder`

From the code you posted it looks like only the constraints for the top label have been set everything else is not there see this screenshot from interface builder of the code you posted:
[image]

I would add the constraints in interface builder like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11762" systemVersion="16C67" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r" launchScreen="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11757"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Hi there this is a label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="3" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO">
                                <rect key="frame" x="225" y="290" width="254" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint id="10" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="height" constant="21"/>
                                    <constraint id="13" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="width" constant="254"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="one more label is here" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="4" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES">
                                <rect key="frame" x="225" y="344" width="231" height="21"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint id="9" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" constant="225"/>
                            <constraint id="12" firstItem="3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="270"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

[image][image]

Generally if you are trying to accommodate for other screens you wouldn't set the leading to have a constant of 225 as other devices will have different screen sizes and it will possibly be off screen. So it is better to try to position the relative to the center vertical or horizontal of a view or using ratios in the constant.

Also to default the storyboard and xib to open with xcode interface builder you can use [this awesome addon from ColbyWilliams](https://github.com/colbylwilliams/DefaultDesigner)

Comment: thank you for the info, your feedback was helpful... since I'm newbie to Xamarin.iOS. Do I need to design my screens in XCODE...?  What's is the best practice?

Comment: I would recommend designing them in Xcode. In terms of functionality for autolayout xcode is slightly more advanced than the Xamarin iOS Designer but this may change as I'm sure xamarin will improve the designer over time.